# How to place annotation stroke on the surface of the object in Blender 2.8?

Tags: grease-pencil, annotation

From what I can tell, the annotation stroke is always placed at the cursor position. I'd like to place it on the faces of the object. Is there a way to do it?

I know I could easily achieve this with Grease Pencil in Draw mode using Stroke Placement option, but I need annotation because the plugin I'm using specifically requires it (Tesselator 1.2, option "Annotation Influence"). I tried it and it works with annotation and does not work with Grease Pencil. But I'm not able to place precise annotation strokes on the surface of the object.

https://blendermarket.com/products/tesselator

[image: Tesselator]

Or maybe there is a way to convert grease pencil into annotation stroke?

Answer (score 5):

I emailed the author of the addon and he sent me a screenshot where this option is located in the newest 2.80 beta build:

[image: annotate active tool placement]